# How to bind an integer value in onBindViewHolder in Adapter class

Tags: android

I am recieving this error for String Resource `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0`, is there any other way to Bind an Integer Value in my onBindVieHolder. `amount` is an integer value and this error is showing on the same line.

My AdapterClass

```
internal class AdapterClass(list: ArrayList<Data>) :
Adapter< MyViewHolder>() {
var list: ArrayList<Data> = list

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
): MyViewHolder {

    val view: View =
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.income_recycler_data, parent, false)


    return MyViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(
    holder: MyViewHolder,
    position: Int
) {
    holder.type.text = list[position].type
    holder.amount.setText(list[position].amount)
    holder.date.text = list[position].date
    holder.note.text = list[position].note
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

internal inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var type: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type_txt_income)
    var amount: TextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount_txt_income)
    var date: TextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_txt_income)
    var note: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_txt_income)

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
holder.amount.setText(list[position].amount)
```

with this:

```
holder.amount.setText(list[position].amount.toString())
```

Comment: But now i lost all of my data, none of data is shown in recyclerView